# NodeJs - Mongoose seem to not pass any query on my code, however I have effectively defined a query to be executed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I would pass the found data on my database using model.find to a value. Primarily I would console.log() the value returns by mongoose to ensure it's a relevant value. But currently when I'm passing a `find query` in my Nodejs database nothing happens. Neither console.log or error occurs. 
So I'm wondering what is broken and how make those element functionning correctly, to get my log, then my value.

here my mongoose.model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema= mongoose.Schema;

var ChatSchema = new Schema({
    ip:{required:true, type: String},
    message: {required:true, type: String},
    room:{required:true, type: String}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Chat", ChatSchema)
```

here my server.js:

```
 var chatScan= Chat.find(ip, function (err, docs) { 
        if(err) return console.log(err)
        return docs.length
})
console.log("chatScan: ", chatScan)
```

Any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: could be any number of things. connection not right, `get` request not right etc etc need more code to be sure.

Comment: the connection effectively! anything work well now

Comment: well, now the function returns me the mongoose.find()'s function definition as following `Query {
  _mongooseOptions: {},
  _transforms: [],
  _hooks: Kareem { _pres: Map {}, _posts: Map {} },
  _executionCount: 0,`

Answer (score 1):

Change `server.js` to:

```
var scannedIp = 12.34.56.78;
var chatScan = Chat.find({ ip: scannedIp }, function (err, docs) {
        if(err) return console.log(err)
        console.log(docs.length)
})
```

**BTW**, the `find` method is a promise, so if you want to `console.log` it's results outside of the callback, then you need to do something like so:

```
chatScan.then(docs => {
  console.log(docs)
})
```